# Why does my TextBox 4,5,6 go to 0 after I click the calculate Button?

Tags: vb.net

I cannot understand why it is only displaying `0`:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim num1, num2, num3 As Integer
    Dim highestValue, middleValue, smallestValue As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        num1 = TextBox1.Text
        num2 = TextBox2.Text
        num3 = TextBox3.Text

        If num1 > num2 > num3 Then
            num1 = highestValue
            num2 = middleValue
            num3 = smallestValue

        ElseIf num2 > num3 > num1 Then
            highestValue = num2
            middleValue = num3
            smallestValue = num1

        ElseIf num3 > num2 > num1 Then
            num3 = highestValue
            num2 = middleValue
            num1 = smallestValue
        End If
        TextBox4.Text = highestValue
        TextBox5.Text = middleValue
        TextBox6.Text = smallestValue
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your first and last condition make no sense. You set `num1`, `num2` and `num3` and then do nothing with them. Then you just set your textbox values at the end to a potentially unset `highestValue`, `middleValue`, `smallestValue`. Step through your code and it will be revealing. The only way I could see your textboxes not being set to 0 is if you hit your second condition of `num2 > num3 > num1`. give that a shot to test by setting textbox1 to 20, textbox2 to 10 and textbox3 to 15. You'll see values show up in your Textbox4, 5, and 6.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict.

Comment: I turned on the option strict but it still hasn't worked...got any other suggestions perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> If num1 > num2 > num3 Then
> ```

This is very likely not what you meant to do. Unless I'm mistaken, it's parsed as follows:

```
If (num1 > num2) > num3 Then
```

In other words:

```
If {bool-expression} > num3 Then
```

Which implies an implicit cast from `Boolean` to `Integer`. Do you have `Option Strict` on?

Did you mean to do this instead?

```
If num1 > num2 AndAlso num2 > num3 Then
```

Also, in all but one of your conditional blocks, `highestValue`, `middleValue` and `smallestValue` are never assigned, and thus have their default value of `0`.

Make sure these variables have a value in all code paths.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to programming and my thinking is that I assigned them to an integer value and then textbox 4-5 if each num> another?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, that's an awfully longwinded way of doing it. As you learn more, you'll become more aware of various language features. Firstly, I would suggest you take the advice from @mathieu

One of the core principles of programming is don't repeat yourself. It's often better to rethink code that is similar and maybe find completely different ways of doing things. For example, this is a different way of approaching the same result ..

Adding the numbers to a list and then using the `.Sort` method built into lists, you can let .net do some of the work for you. Also the code is shorter, cleaner, easier to maintain and less prone to errors. These are also some of the fundamentals of programming. Keep at it! :)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    num1 = TextBox1.Text
    num2 = TextBox2.Text
    num3 = TextBox3.Text

    Dim tempList As New List(Of Double)

    tempList.Add(Val(TextBox1.Text))
    tempList.Add(Val(TextBox2.Text))
    tempList.Add(Val(TextBox3.Text))

    tempList.Sort()

    TextBox4.Text = tempList(2).ToString
    TextBox5.Text = tempList(1).ToString
    TextBox6.Text = tempList(0).ToString
End Sub
```